# 'flutter doctor' returns '\flutter\bin\cache was unexpected at this time.'

Tags: flutter, sdk

I have downloaded flutter_windows_1.17.1-stable and extracted it outside the program files, yet whenever I run the 'flutter doctor' command I am getting the message '\flutter\bin\cache was unexpected at this time.'

I have searched about this and found few solutions suggesting to delete the cache folder in bin of flutter directory, I did that, also added the path in environment variables, still having the same message.

[image: '\flutter\bin\cache was unexpected at this time.' message]

Please, I need suggestion on how to fix this.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you read https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#update-your-path where the path in in your welcome screen

Comment: already did it, still the same output.

Answer (score 6):

Faced similar issue, I initially created C:\Program Files(Manual)\Flutter
and added to user env path variable, but got Cache error, only when I moved to c:\src\Flutter it worked, I'd say paths with spaces (and or special chars '(' ')'  ' ' aren't accepted

Answer (score 1):

While you're using windows, go to the **system environment variables** from the search and edit flutter path variable, change it to the binary folder like *C:\src\flutter\bin*.

Comment: did it, still having the same output.

Comment: Try to delete and re-install flutter to *C:\src* then go and apply this answer

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this issue, I had already installed flutter several times to fix previous errors. This issue can happen if flutter is not installed in your environment variables, but it also happens if there is another duplicate or path to another bin in the same host. Also, make sure to check on all places for duplicate paths to two or more flutter bins. There are environment variables for your account, and environment variables for the entire PC. Be sure to check in both

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you extract all your files to c:/src/flutter
2. If the problem is still there , then to run commands use c:/src/flutter/bin
   I.e., include bin to your path

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I tried all the above solutions, but they did not work. So I also changed the path. The solution was to direct the CMD to Flutter's main directory.
Example: You want to run the code `flutter doctor`. You expect to open the CMD and run the code, so you get the result while you have configured the env and path, but it does not. To run the code, go to the same directory you installed the flutter and then run your codes;

```
 E:\Program Files\flutter> flutter doctor
```

I hope it works for you as it worked for me. GL

Answer (score 0):

1.) Move the Flutter folder to your C Drive.
2.) Create a new Folder called "src".
3.) Move Flutter folder to src.
4.) Add C:\src\flutter\bin to Path in Control Panel -> User Accounts -> Enviorments -> Path -> edit

Answer (score 0):

first if you changed your flutter's location and if you gave path again to variables, you you need to dalate old path of flutter and it works.

Answer (score 0):

get sure of The Name Directory doesn't include space
Don’t install Flutter to a directory or path that meets one or both of the following conditions:

```
The path contains special characters or spaces.
The path requires elevated privileges.
```

As an example, C:\Program Files fails both conditions.
and then :

Press Windows + Pause.

If your keyboard lacks a Pause key, try Windows + Fn + B.

The System > About dialog displays.

Click Advanced System Settings > Advanced > Environment Variables…

The Environment Variables dialog displays.

In the User variables for (username) section, look for the Path entry.
The Edit Environment Variable dialog displays.

```
Double-click in an empty row.

Type %Flutter SDK Location%flutter\bin.

Click the %Flutter SDK Location%flutter\bin entry.

Click Move Up until the Flutter entry sits at the top of the list.

Click OK three times.
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend to:

- delete flutter folder
- re-downlowd again, the same version you have used

Comment: Maybe it is the incomplete phrasing, maybe the lack of punctuation, but I do not see how this answers the question. Could you rephrase and otherwise [edit] according to [answer] in order to make more obvious what solution you propose to the problem described at the top of this page, its effect and why it helps to solve the problem? Taking the [tour] might give you the right mind set.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried to improve readability of your post. Please review and improve if necessary, ideally according to [answer] (I can't because I do not really know what you mean, not to speak of the necessary details for making a good answer).